# How to send data over DTLS?

Tags: netty

I'm new to Netty and trying to implement a basic data transmission module that supports DTLS protocol.

So, I've searched bunch of documents but nothing worked for me.

Is there any simple DTLS example implemented by Netty library??

Comment: If you just search for a java DTLS library, Scandium, a part of the open source project Eclipse/Californium, offers that. Unfortunately I don't know, if netty supports it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Netty does not have any support for DTLS out of the box. That said you could built it by yourself by implementing a ChannelHandler and put it into the pipeline